# How create an object with enum as a parameter in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have a class

```
public enum CustomerType {
    GOLD, SILVER, IRON, RUSTY

}
```

and another class :

```
@Entity
```

public class Customer implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private CustomerType type;


public Customer(){};
public Customer(String firstName, String lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, CustomerType type){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.type = type;
}

public String getFirstName(){ return firstName;}
public String getLastName(){ return lastName;}
public Integer getId() {   return id; }
public CustomerType getType(){ return type;}

public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id;}
public void setFirstName(String firstName){this.firstName = firstName;}
public void setLastName(String lastName ){this.lastName = lastName;}
public void setType(CustomerType type){this.type = type;}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Customer)) {
        return false;
    }
    Customer other = (Customer) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "entity.Customer[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
```

}

i have a constructor with parameters firstName, lastName, CustomerType type

in another class i want to create customer like this

```
Customer c1 = new Customer("ida", "heartless", GOLD);
```

but it just won't let put enum parameter like this. How can I proper use enum? What i'm missing?

Comment: there is a constructor and a get and set method for CustomerType field in the customer class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `CustomerType.GOLD` instead of just `GOLD`.

Comment: or perform a static import

Comment: when I do this and run then it gives me this fail in netbeans:Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project books: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: @JohnnyVan did you import the Enum?

Comment: yes! import enums.CustomerType;

Comment: @JohnnyVan It would be helpful if you could provide code for Customer class.

Comment: ive just loaded the code for my Customer class

Comment: @JohnnyVan I don't see the import there.

Comment: package entity;

import enums.CustomerType;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that you just need import in your `Customer` class.
and after that it should looks like this:

```
Customer c1 = new Customer("ida", "heartless", CustomerType.GOLD);
```